# How to disable TreeView auto first node select

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

I've searched the Google a little bit but I couldn't find something useful. The TreeView's behavior is like when you add a node to it's tree, it will be selected by default and that means always you should have a selected node except the moments that the Tree is empty.

Is there any way to override or disable this?

Comment: you can preserve the previous selected node in an object and then add nodes, then set the selected node to the preserved node.

Comment: This is a good way to do with roots, but if the selected node would be under any parent node then I got to remember the parent and then add back the preserved nodes to the proper parent. Is there any other way?

Comment: I think you can preserve the selected node by it's KEY, then you will not need to remember the parent, and even if you are sure you need the parent node, you can find it with a foreach loop and find out who your preserved node's father is.

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying about preserving. You mean that store the node in a TreeNode object or what? Would mind to say an example.

Comment: TreeView tv1 = new TreeView();  
    TreeNode selected = tv1.SelectedNode;  
    //do your add here  
    tv1.SelectedNode = selected;

Answer (score 5):

Use a higher tabindex value – i.e., once your form loads the first tabstop should not be your TreeView control.

```
TreeView1.TabIndex = 2;
```

or u can also use

```
TreeView1.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that as being the problem!  Now if I can just figure out how to disable the ability to select any nodes I'll be in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
yourNode.SelectAction=TreeNodeSelectAction.None
```

;

Comment: This seems to be working. I have never seen `SelectAction` before. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: I'am happy to help you MahanGM

Comment: No 'SelectAction property in the Windows Forms TreeView TreeNode.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is ancient, but I found a solution to it that works better than the above.
I generally don't want any entry to be selected unless the user selects it. I found that in addition to the OP's case auto selection also happens when the TreeView is in a splitpanel that gets collapsed (for some reason).

The solution for me was using the `BeforeSelect` event.

```
private void GroupingTV_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Prevent node selection by any other means than the user
    if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.ByMouse && e.Action != TreeViewAction.ByKeyboard)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

}
```

Of course, if you need to trigger selection by code, you'll need to override this with an extra flag you set before triggering selection:

```
Intentional = true;
GroupingTV.SelectedNode = node;
Intentional = false;
```

```
private void GroupingTV_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Prevent node selection by any other means than the user and intentional calls via code.
    if (!Intentional && e.Action != TreeViewAction.ByMouse && e.Action != TreeViewAction.ByKeyboard)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

}
```

Or, if you have a lot of treeviews and don't want to have loads of flags, temporarily disable the handler:

```
GroupingTV.AfterSelect -= GroupingTV_BeforeSelect;
GroupingTV.SelectedNode = node;
GroupingTV_BeforeSelect += GroupingTV_BeforeSelect;
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeView tv1 = new TreeView();  
TreeNode selected = tv1.SelectedNode;  
//do your add here  
tv1.SelectedNode = selected;
```

Comment: This won't disable the node selection. Besides, I'm using the visual TreeView, not the code based one. Right now this is just like I get the selected node and then put it back to selection, so what's the difference while the TreeView still can't make node unselected?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got you just now, you want to have no selected node, right?
that is as simple as :

```
treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
```

Comment: when i set the selectedNode to null i have no selected node, that's weird, can you upload your code?

Comment: I mean the selected node in the TreeView which is highlighted not the property.